# Container bound apps script deploy from manifest can allow other user read data from container spreadsheet without sharing file

Tags: google-apps-script, manifest, chatbot

I am developing chatbot through container (Spreadsheet) bound apps script deploy from manifest for may internal organization members, the members can request info stored on the sheets by simply typing and sending through google chat.

Members can get the info automatically by the chatbot if I share the spreadsheet, otherwise the bot is not responding message replied.

When I share the file, the shard copy also appear to all of the members drive too. I want make that content read by user without sharing the Container spreadsheet.

What code I have to add to my script so that user get the permission to read my file during chatting. Is this possible?

My manifest code is as follows

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Sheets",
        "serviceId": "sheets",
        "version": "v4"
      }
    ],
    "libraries": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "OAuth2",
        "libraryId": "1B7FSrk5Zi6L1rSxxTDgDEUsPzlukDsi4KGuTMorsTQHhGBzBkMun4iDF",
        "version": "40"
      }
    ]
  },
 
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "chat": {
    "addToSpaceFallbackMessage": "Hi ! Thanks for adding me. Type help to get more.."
  }
}
```

and user oauth2 ..

```
/**
 * Configures the Chatbot service.
 */
function getChatbotService() {
 return OAuth2.createService("chat-sheet-bot")
 // Set the endpoint URL.
 .setTokenUrl("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token")
// Set the private key and issuer.
 .setPrivateKey(PRIVATE_KEY)
 .setIssuer(CLIENT_EMAIL)
// Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
 .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
// Set the scope.
 .setScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have solved the problem as follows:

1. added get service method with spreadsheet scope as

```
/**
 * Configures the spreadsheet service.
 */
function getSpreasheetService() {
 return OAuth2.createService("spreadsheet")
 // Set the endpoint URL.
 .setTokenUrl("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token")
// Set the private key and issuer.
 .setPrivateKey(PRIVATE_KEY)
 .setIssuer(CLIENT_EMAIL)
// Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
 .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
// Set the scope.
 .setScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets");
}
```

2. added method read sheet to get data from spreadsheet by the service account using spreadsheet api

```
function readSheet(){
  var service = getSpreasheetService();
  var ssID = 'your Spreadsheet Id' 
  var range = 'Sheet1!A3:E';
  var url = 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/' + ssId +'/values/' + range;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken() } }); 
  var rep = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var values =  rep.values;
  for(row in values)
    Logger.log(values[row][0] + ":" + values[row][2] + ":" + values[row][3] + ":" + values[row][4]);
  //now i can use these data to reply back to end user as message
}
```

3. I shared the spreadsheet to the service account which looks like "your-service-account@sys................iam.gserviceaccount.com"
4. I enabled the Sheet API in Google Cloud Project console on API & Services

oh! it works with great charm.